# Read Json Data.But able to access the second Object

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How To Read this Data

```
"Data": [
    {
        "Candidate Details": {
            "Salutation": "au.linkedin.com/in/324234",
            "First Name": "test (Demo)",
            "Last Name": "1MORN,2AFTE",
            "Nationality": "",
            "Australian Residency / Visa Status": "1PR",
            "Email": "testn@324234.com",
            "Mobile No.": "2345234",
            "Home Telephone": "234234",
            "Work Telephone": "234234"
        },
        "[Current Residential Address]": {
            "City / Town": "234243",
            "Province / State": "23423",
            "ZIP / Post Code": "234234",
            "Country": "0_AU"
        },
        "[Education & Experience]": {
            "Seniority": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "Speciality": "",
            "Highest Education": "This is a test resume submitted with the following account details:\r\nnotes",
            "Professional Qualification": "great exp",
            "Educational Summary": "234234 in 234 First Aid",
            "Work Experience": "2006-07-23 06:59:59",
            "Australian Work Experience": "EMP",
            "Work Experience Years": "Z_11+",
            "Medical Registration": "GENER"
        },
        "[Availability & Preferences]": {
            "Current Employment Status": "none",
            "Can Relocate?": "",
            "Available to Start": "01-Jan-1970",
            "Salary Range": "",
            "Location Preference": "1_profile1376113217.jpg",
            "Positions Interested In?": "234234.doc"
        },
        "Additional Notes": [
            "324(Demo)"
        ]
    }
```

I can easily read Candidate Details but variable not access the [Current Residential Address].
Code is written below

```
var ss = o["Data"];
        JArray s = ss as JArray;
        var dt = s.ToArray();
        foreach (var dss in dt)
        {
            var dtt = dss["Candidate Details"];
         }
```

dtt Gets only first Record but not Select the rest on the parameters.

Comment: As an aside, it's worth putting more effort into naming your variables - none of `o`, `s`, `ss`, `dt`, `dss` or `dtt` give *any* indication as to their meaning.

Comment: json is not proper format.that's way i need to filter this data like .i'm already waste 1 hour..

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "is not proper format". If my answer *isn't* what you want, you need to be a lot clearer about what you *do* want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array only has one entry - which in turn has properties of `"Candidate Details"`, `"[Current Residential Address]"` etc. (It's not clear whether this really need to be an array at all.)

If you want to iterate over all the properties, you can use:

```
// Your array entry is an object
foreach (JObject candidate in s)
{
    foreach (var pair in candidate)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
}
```

or if you know the properties you want, you can fetch each of them by name, as you're already doing for candidate details.

Comment: How Can i add this data to data dictionary

Comment: @RichardRay: I have no idea what you mean by "data dictionary" here. You need to be a *lot* clearer.

Comment: thnx jon 4 repply,  Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    dictionary.ToList().ForEach(x => dictionary.Add(pair.Key, x.Value));

Comment: @RichardRay: Nope, that's still not clear - particularly as each value within the object is another object, not a string. Please take some time to clarify your question - make it *really* clear what you're trying to achieve. See http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints for more details.

Comment: i just fill the form using this data.